# Python program is stuck when running, neither reporting an error, nor stopping, nor moving, what is the reason?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from termcolor import cprint
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import keyboard
import gc


def initialize_chessboard(size=20):
    m = np.zeros((size+2, size+2), dtype=int)
    return m


def random_colors(colors_list):
    return random.sample(colors_list, 4)


def configure_small_checkerboard_colors(size=20):
    nb_chess_color_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    color_list = []
    remaining_quantity = size**2
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        nb_chess_color_list[i] = random.randint(1, remaining_quantity)
        if nb_chess_color_list[i] > remaining_quantity/2 or nb_chess_color_list[i] < remaining_quantity/4:
            nb_chess_color_list[i] = 0
        else:
            remaining_quantity = remaining_quantity - nb_chess_color_list[i]
            i += 1
    # print(nb_chess_color_list)

    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(nb_chess_color_list[i]):
            color_list.append(i+1)
    # print(color_list)
    # print(len(color_list))
    # print(sum(nb_chess_color_list))
    for i in range(size**2-len(color_list)):
        color_list.append(0)
    # print(len(color_list))

    small_chessboard = np.array(color_list).reshape(size,size)

    # print(small_chessboard)

    return small_chessboard


def configure_checkerboard_colors(chessboard, size):
    for i in range(size):
        chessboard[0][i+1] = 1
        chessboard[i+1][0] = 2
        chessboard[i+1][-1] = 3
        chessboard[-1][i+1] = 4

    # for i in range(size+2):
    #     print(chessboard[i])

    return chessboard

def disrupt_the_chessboard(chessboard):
    m = chessboard.ravel()
    np.random.shuffle(m)
    chessboard = m.reshape(size,size)
    # print('-----------------')
    # print(m)
    # print(chessboard)
    return chessboard

def key_up():
    # print('up')
    global small_chessboard,chessboard
    # cache = np.array(0)

    for i in range(size):
        cache_1 = small_chessboard[:, i].tolist()

        cache_2 = []
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(cache_1)):
            chess = cache_1[j]
            if chess == 0:
                count += 1
                if count >= len(cache_1):
                    continue
            else:
                cache_2.append(chess)
        if count < len(cache_1):
            for j in range(count):
                cache_2.append(0)
            while chessboard[0][i+1] == cache_2[0] or cache_2[0] == 0:
                cache_2.pop(0)
                cache_2.append(0)
            small_chessboard[:, i] = np.array(cache_2).T
        else:
            small_chessboard[:, i] = np.array(cache_1).T
        del cache_1,cache_2,count,i,j
        gc.collect()
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)

def key_down():
    # print('down')
    global small_chessboard,chessboard
    # cache = np.array(0)

    for i in range(size):
        cache_1 = small_chessboard[:, i].tolist()

        cache_2 = []
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(cache_1)):
            chess = cache_1[j]
            if chess == 0:
                count += 1
                if count >= len(cache_1):
                    continue
            else:
                cache_2.append(chess)
        if count < len(cache_1):
            for j in range(count):
                cache_2.insert(0, 0)
            while chessboard[-1][i+1] == cache_2[-1] or cache_2[-1] == 0:
                cache_2.pop(-1)
                cache_2.insert(0,0)
            small_chessboard[:, i] = np.array(cache_2).T
        else:
            small_chessboard[:, i] = np.array(cache_1).T
        del cache_1,cache_2,count,i,j
        gc.collect()
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)

def key_left():
    # print('left')
    global small_chessboard,chessboard
    small_chessboard = small_chessboard.tolist()
    for i in range(size):
        cache_1 = small_chessboard[i]
        cache_2 = []
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(cache_1)):
            chess = cache_1[j]
            if chess == 0:
                count += 1
                if count >= len(cache_1):
                    continue
            else:
                cache_2.append(chess)
        if count < len(cache_1):
            for j in range(count):
                cache_2.append(0)
            while chessboard[i+1][0] == cache_2[0] or cache_2[0] == 0:
                cache_2.pop(0)
                cache_2.append(0)
            small_chessboard[i] = cache_2
        else:
            small_chessboard[i] = cache_1
    del cache_1,cache_2,count,i,j
    gc.collect()
    small_chessboard = np.array(small_chessboard)
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)



def key_right():
    # print('right')
    global small_chessboard,chessboard
    small_chessboard = small_chessboard.tolist()
    for i in range(size):
        cache_1 = small_chessboard[i]
        cache_2 = []
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(cache_1)):
            chess = cache_1[j]
            if chess == 0:
                count += 1
                if count >= len(cache_1):
                    continue
            else:
                cache_2.append(chess)
        if count < len(cache_1):
            for j in range(count):
                cache_2.insert(0, 0)
            while chessboard[i+1][-1] == cache_2[-1] or cache_2[-1] == 0:
                cache_2.pop(-1)
                cache_2.insert(0,0)
            small_chessboard[i] = cache_2
        else:
            small_chessboard[i] = cache_1
    del cache_1,cache_2,count,i,j
    gc.collect()

    small_chessboard = np.array(small_chessboard)
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)

def key_r():
    # print('R')
    global small_chessboard
    small_chessboard = disrupt_the_chessboard(small_chessboard)
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)

def chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard):
    os.system('cls')
    final_small_chessboard = small_chessboard
    final_small_chessboard = np.insert(final_small_chessboard, 0, 0, axis=0)
    final_small_chessboard = np.insert(final_small_chessboard, 0, 0, axis=1)
    final_small_chessboard = np.append(final_small_chessboard,[np.zeros(len(final_small_chessboard[0]),dtype=int).tolist()], axis=0)
    final_small_chessboard = np.append(final_small_chessboard,np.zeros((len(final_small_chessboard[::,0]),1),dtype=int).tolist(), axis=1)
    # print(final_small_chessboard)
    final_chessboard = final_small_chessboard + chessboard
    
    # print(final_chessboard)
    # return final_chessboard

    display_color(final_chessboard)
    del final_chessboard
    gc.collect()


def interactive_interface(small_chessboard, chessboard):
    print('Use the arrow keys to control the game')
    print('Input R to disrupt the board')

    keyboard.add_hotkey('up', key_up)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('down', key_down)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('left', key_left)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('right', key_right)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('r', key_r)

    recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')

    #当按下esc时结束按键监听，并输出所有按键事件
    # print(recorded)

def display_color(final_chessboard):
    for i in final_chessboard:
        a = 1
        for j in i:
            if a == len(i):
                if j == 0:
                    print('  ')
                    a+=1
                else:
                    cprint('  ',on_color=chess_color_list[j-1])
                    a+=1
            else:
                if j == 0:
                    print('  ',end='')
                    a+=1
                else:
                    cprint('  ',on_color=chess_color_list[j-1],end='')
                    a+=1
    #time.sleep(1)


def start():
    global small_chessboard, chessboard
    # size = 20
    # COLORS_LIST = ['on_grey', 'on_red', 'on_green', 'on_yellow','on_blue', 'on_magenta', 'on_cyan', 'on_white']
    chessboard = initialize_chessboard(size)
    
    configure_checkerboard_colors(chessboard, size)
    small_chessboard = configure_small_checkerboard_colors(size)
    small_chessboard = disrupt_the_chessboard(small_chessboard)
    # print(chessboard)
    # print(small_chessboard)
    chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)
    interactive_interface(small_chessboard, chessboard)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 20
    # COLORS_LIST = ['on_grey', 'on_red', 'on_green', 'on_yellow','on_blue', 'on_magenta', 'on_cyan', 'on_white']
    COLORS_LIST = ['on_red', 'on_green', 'on_yellow','on_blue', 'on_magenta', 'on_cyan', 'on_white']
    chess_color_list = random_colors(COLORS_LIST)
    start()
```

I'm a beginner. I tried writing a little game in python, but I ran into a problem that I couldn't solve.
The program ran for a while and got stuck, there was no error, it was stuck there and did not move.
I dont konw why :(

The code I provided is a Python script that implements a simple interactive game with a chessboard-like interface. Here's a breakdown of what the code does:

1. It imports necessary libraries such as `time`, `termcolor`, `numpy`, `random`, `os`, `keyboard`, and `gc` (garbage collector).
2. The function `initialize_chessboard(size)` creates a square numpy array filled with zeros representing the chessboard.
3. The function `random_colors(colors_list)` takes a list of colors and returns a random sample of four colors from the list.
4. The function `configure_small_checkerboard_colors(size)` generates a small chessboard by randomly assigning colors to its cells based on certain conditions.
5. The function `configure_checkerboard_colors(chessboard, size)` assigns colors to the border cells of the main chessboard.
6. The function `disrupt_the_chessboard(chessboard)` shuffles the colors in the chessboard randomly.
7. The functions `key_up()`, `key_down()`, `key_left()`, `key_right()`, and `key_r()` are event handlers for different keyboard keys. They modify the state of the chessboard based on the key pressed.
8. The function `chessboard_integration(small_chessboard, chessboard)` integrates the small chessboard into the main chessboard and displays the resulting chessboard on the console.
9. The function `interactive_interface(small_chessboard, chessboard)` sets up the keyboard event listeners and handles user input.
10. The function `display_color(final_chessboard)` displays the colors of the chessboard on the console using colored text.
11. The `start()` function initializes the game by setting up the chessboard, small chessboard, and colors. It then calls the `chessboard_integration()` and `interactive_interface()` functions to start the game.
12. Finally, the script checks if it's being run as the main module and calls the `start()` function to begin the game.

Comment: The most likely place you are stuck is in a while loop. In `configure_small_checkerboard_colors` you have `while i < 4`but you only increment `i` if you enter the `else`. If the condition is always True, `i` will never change and you'll never exit the loop. It might not be there as it's your only `while` loop, but they're probably the right places to investigate first.

Comment: The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)